# How to add google doodle?

Tags: google

I want to know that for whom google adds doodles on its home page? Suppose if I want to add google doodle for my birthday on google homepage then is it possible to do so..?
If it is possible then please let me know how to do so. I have gmail and google+ accounts.

Comment: Belongs on webapps.

Comment: @paulmorriss - no it doesn't belong on Web Apps. It'd get closed as not a real question.

Comment: @ChrisF I think it's a good question, and the answer below is good.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add or submit doodles, though Google do run competitions for children from time to time.

Google have a full time staff dedicated to the project, they decide who and what to honour. See [Google Logo on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_logo#Google_Doodle) for full details.